# Real device crash when loading activity with background

Tags: java, android

I have an activity where user can create profile. I want to add background image. I added that image to drawable folder (I just copied that picture from desktop and pasted to drawable). Everything works fine on virtual device. But when I'm trying to run app on my real device it crashes. When I remove background it's not crashing. What could cause the problem?

I tried to set background in my activity_profile.xml but result was same

**content_profile.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.gvidas.activities.ProfileActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_profile">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/bg"
        android:scaleType = "fitXY"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_profile.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:alpha="0.8"
    tools:context="com.example.gvidas.activities.ProfileActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_profile" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="175dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent">


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/profileNameTextField"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
            android:hint="First Name"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textColorHint="#ffffff" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/profileAgeTextField"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/profileNameTextField"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
            android:hint="Age"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textColorHint="#ffffff" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/profileHeightTextField"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/profileAgeTextField"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
            android:hint="Height"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textColorHint="#ffffff" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/profileWeightTextField"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/profileHeightTextField"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
            android:hint="Weight"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:shadowColor="#ffffff"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textColorHint="#ffffff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/saveProfile"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/profileWeightTextField"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
            android:text="Save"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:theme="@style/ButtonSave" />


    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: please update your question with crash log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image is probably too large and it's causing memory problems.

Using an image loader library like Glide will prevent the crash. But it still would not be optimal. You also need to reduce your image size in project.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I reduce image size and resolution with photoshop just to see if that was the problem and you are correct!